# Aws S3 Only PutObject Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policies

i'm trying to setup a **Only PutObject** policy to by bucket as following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt####",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However when i try to upload a file thought `AWS SDK` I receive a 403 response from AWS.
I'm absolutely sure to use the correct access key of the IAM user that has this policy attached to it.

Anyone knows why AWS3 complain with this policy when it shouldn't?

**Edit:**

After hours of trials, I came across a weird behaviour which i would like to be explained.

If I add `s3:ListBucket` to the above policy it just works fine. Without it, it will return a 403. Why amazon force me to put **ListBucket** action when i don't want to have it?

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Best way to troubleshoot this is to give your policy following action and resources:

```
"Action": [
    "s3:*"
],
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
]
```

This will confirm you're using correct access key. If it goes through, you're most likely using unauthorized actions (e.g. s3:ListBucket). You can use CloudTrail to find which unauthorized actions are being called.

Comment: Thank you a lot @aalimovs, i try it a lots combination and I came a cross that if I don't put `ListBucket` **Action** to the policy it give 403, if I add that it succesfully upload the file, do you know why this happen?

Comment: Can you show how exactly you are uploading the file?

Comment: Thanks for your support, i'm uploading files trough **filesystem** library of PHP https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem,  and using the Aws3 adapter: https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3,

Uploading function: https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/blob/master/src/AwsS3Adapter.php#L495